# Need Help in Rendering Dynamic Component in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-dynamic-components

hi there i have the following situation .
I have parent component (Health Profile) that lists child subcomponents with add button on each . I want to make the application such a way that when user clicks on add button only form to that specific component opens up and rest are closed and vice versa . I m unable to make use of **v-bind:is**  because the button is in the subcomponent and it emits the data to parent component.
Any help will be appreciated .attached the screenshot   [Health Profile Component with each subcomponent having button that fires emmit data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqyDE.png)

Comment: You probably should use v-bind:is. The reason you gave about being unable to use v-bind is easily solved by emitting and responding to events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please next time provide a code snippet to better understand your code

You can use an event bus to propagate the button click throughout the project.

```
// event-bus.js
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

Then import this in your component

```
// component-a.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import EventBus from './event-bus';
Vue.component('component-a', {
...
methods: {
  emitMethod () {
    EventBus.$emit('EVENT_NAME', payLoad);
  }
}
});
```

Check out this [article](https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860)